# How to copy tmux entire buffer to clipboard?

Tags: tmux

I can do this now by running this command `capture-pane -S -3000` and using this keybind:

```
bind C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | clip"
```

Which requires me remembering to type `capture-pane -S -3000` and pressing `Ctrl+B`, `Ctrl+Y`.

I would like to do it in one step like:

```
bind C-y capture-pane -S -3000; run "tmux save-buffer - | clip"
```

But it does not work.

Optimally, it would be nice if `tmux` asked how many lines I would like to copy from the buffer. For exemple:

```
bind C-y capture-pane -S -ASK_HOW_MANY_LINE_TO_INPUT; run "tmux save-buffer - | clip"
```

Then, if I press `Ctrl+B`, `Ctrl+Y`, I would type 3000 and press enter to get the last 3000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind C-y run "tmux capture-pane -pS-|clip"

bind C-y command-prompt -p "How many lines?" 'run "tmux capture-pane -pS-%%%|clip"'

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer would be using `xclip -i` instead of `clip`:`

```
bind-key C-y run "tmux capture-pane -pS-|xclip -i"

bind-key C-y command-prompt -p "How many lines?" 'run "tmux capture-pane -pS-%%%|xclip -i"'
```

But still not working because `tmux` is very bugged. After the first time I use this, `tmux` stop working and ignores me when I press `Ctrl+B`, `Ctrl+Y`.

You only hope will be trying to use https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank but even that do not work if you are over an SSH connection. Therefore there is nothing you can do about this other that do not use this feature and do everything manually with:

1. To save the your last 3000 history lines `Ctrl+B` e `Shift+:` and type: `capture-pane -S -3000` to copy them to the `tmux` buffer.
2. Lastly, press `Ctrl+B`, `Shift+:` and type `save-buffer ~/filename.txt` to save your console history to a file. You must you an absolute path because `tmux` does not respect your current directly and will save it anywhere.
3. Now, you have to copy the file contents from your remote machine to your local computer. Just connect to your remote machine with `Filezilla` or `WinSCP` if you are on Windows.