# Copy all text in a tmux pane?

Tags: logs, tmux, clipboard, text

How can I copy *all* the text in a tmux pane?

Pressing `Ctrl + b` and `]` I can select a portion of text, but it is cumbersome to scroll all the way to the top in a long pane.

Is there an easier way to select / copy *all* the text from the pane in one go?

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513121/how-to-copy-tmux-entire-buffer-to-clipboard